# Generic Comparator Using Class Fields & Lambda Java

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have a grid in which i have to display some/all fields of a Java Class,
this grid displays the List of elements of that class type.

I have to sort this list provided:

- Class type of the List item
- Field name of the class to be sorted

to get field from a class by field name

```
private static <T> Field getField(Class<T> clazz,String fieldName){
    Field field = null;
    try {
        field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    }catch(java.lang.NoSuchFieldException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return field;
}
```

and the comparator method using lambda, providing class type, field name to sort, and sort order

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> getGenericComparatorLambda(Class<T> clazz,
        String fieldName,boolean orderByAsc){

    //get field from class
    final Field field = getField(clazz, fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);

    //Lambda comparator
    Comparator<T> orderByComparator = (f1, f2) -> {

        Comparable compA = null;
        Comparable compB = null;

        // getting fields from object f1,f2
        try {
            compA =(Comparable) field.get(f1);
            compB =(Comparable) field.get(f2);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // handling null comparators
        if(compA == null)
            return -1;
        else if(compB == null)
            return 1;

        return compA.compareTo(compB);
    };

    //reverse comparator if order is descending
    if (orderByComparator != null && !orderByAsc)
        orderByComparator = orderByComparator.reversed();

    return orderByComparator;   
}
```

As the code consists of Lambda as well as generics of java,
I want an overall analysis of the code, improvements where needed, how much is the performance penalty when using generics with long lists.

Comment: You should not catch exception and continue with a `null` field. That is just exchanging the `NoSuchFieldException` with a `NullPointerException`. Further, the test `orderByComparator != null` at the end is obsolete, it is impossible that `orderByComparator` is `null`. And your comparator is inconsistent, if both `compA` and `compB` are `null`, you are returning `-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want suggestions for improvement, here is one:

The following code:

```
private static <T> Field getField(Class<T> clazz,String fieldName){
    Field field = null;
    try {
        field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    }catch(java.lang.NoSuchFieldException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return field;
}
```

is best rewritten as follows:

```
private static <T> Field getField(Class<T> clazz,String fieldName) {
    try {
        return clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    }catch(java.lang.NoSuchFieldException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The following code:

```
//Lambda comparator
Comparator<T> orderByComparator = (f1, f2) -> {

    Comparable compA = null;
    Comparable compB = null;

    // getting fields from object f1,f2
    try {
        compA =(Comparable) field.get(f1);
        compB =(Comparable) field.get(f2);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // handling null comparators
    if(compA == null)
        return -1;
    else if(compB == null)
        return 1;

    return compA.compareTo(compB);
};
```

is best rewritten as follows:

```
Comparator<T> orderByComparator = (f1, f2) -> {
    Comparable compA, compB;
    try {
        compA = (Comparable) field.get(f1);
        compB = (Comparable) field.get(f2);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return Objects.compare(compA, compB, Comparator.naturalOrder());
};
```

in short:

- lose the useless comments; a comment is only useful if it says something that is not immediately obvious by looking at the code
- do not initialize variables to nonsensical values, because then the compiler will not warn you when you forget to assign something meaningful to them
- if you do not know what to do with an exception, do not print a stack trace, throw a runtime exception instead.

Generics and lambdas have no impact on performance.